# Insert HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, append

I am trying to insert an HTML element (in my file it is called "baseketTotal"). This element is something like a checkout form that has the total price and etc... The thing is that I am trying to put it only on the last movie in the list which I add to the bag.
In this link, it is a picture of how it looks now. So I need to display it only on the last movie, no matter if the list has 1,2, or 10 movies. Only on the last one.

[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Filmovizija</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Filmovizija</h1>
    <div class="prozor"></div>
    <h2>Shooping bag</h2>
    <div class="shooping-cart"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #22254b;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.prozor {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.movie {
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #373b69;
  margin: 25px;
}

.movie-info {
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  align-items: center;
}

.movie img {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  height: 450px;
}

.movie-info h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
}

.movie-info span {
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #22254b;
  padding: 3px 7px;
}

.movie .kupi {
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  align-items: center;
}

.movie .kupi button {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.movie .kupi span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* ----------------------------------- SHOOPING CART ------------------------------------------------ */

.shooping-cart {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

h2 {
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted grey;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item span {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
}

.smallPic {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item .opis {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item .opis h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item .opis h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: antiquewhite;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item .kolicina input {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.shooping-cart .single-item .kolicina button {
  padding: 2px 6px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 0;
}

.single-total {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

/* ----------------------------------- SHOOPING CART TOTAL ALL ------------------------------------------------ */

.totalKosara {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 350px;
  height: 160px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.potvrdi {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.potvrdi .sub,
.price {
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.blue button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #0b1050;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: inherit;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

scriptJS
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "cd782e9b03mshbd50bac036f1802p16179djsn48c38f33f263",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "online-movie-database.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};

const main = document.querySelector(`.prozor`);
const shoopingCart = document.querySelector(`.shooping-cart`);
const checkoutBtn = document.querySelector(`.checkoutBtn`);

fetch(
  "https://online-movie-database.p.rapidapi.com/auto-complete?q=hacker",
  options
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const list = data.d;
    list.map((item) => {
      const name = item.l;
      const rank = item.rank;
      const price = Math.floor(rank / 100);
      const poster = item.i.imageUrl;
      const movie = ` <div class="movie">
               <img src=${poster} alt="${name}" />
                           <div class="movie-info">
                              <h3>${name}</h3>
                              <span>#${rank}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="kupi">
                              <button class="addToBag">Kupi film</button>
                              <span>${price} HRK</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>`;
      main.innerHTML += movie;

      //---------------------------------- add to basket --------------------------//

      const button = document.querySelectorAll(`.addToBag`);
      button.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener(`click`, function (e) {
          const clicked = e.target;
          const kupi = clicked.closest(`.kupi`);
          const cijena2 = kupi.querySelector(`span`).innerText;
          const cijena = cijena2.split(` `)[0];
          const parent = kupi.closest(`.movie`);
          const imeFilma = parent.querySelector(`.movie-info h3`).innerText;
          const imgSrc = parent.querySelector(`img`).src;

          const singleItem = `
         
             <div class="single-item">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined deleteItem"> close </span>
               <img src=${imgSrc} alt="aaa" class="smallPic" />
                   <div class="opis">
                       <h2>${imeFilma}</h2>
                    </div>
                   <div class="kolicina">
                      <button class="plus">+</button>
                     <input type="text" value="1" max="3" min="1" class="input"/>
                     <button class="minus">-</button>
                   </div>
               <div class="single-total" data-value="${cijena}">${cijena} KN</div>
             </div>
            
          `;

          shoopingCart.innerHTML += singleItem;

          const basketTotal = `
          <div class="totalKosara vidljivo">
        <div class="potvrdi">
          <p class="sub">Subtotal</p>
          <p class="price">675 KN</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <p>Shipping, taxes and discounts calculated at checkout.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blue"><button>Checkout</button></div>
      </div>
          `;

          const removeElement = function () {
            const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`.single-item`);
            let lastNode = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
            console.log(lastNode);
          };

          removeElement();

          //OBRISI ITEM
          const deleteItem = document.querySelectorAll(`.deleteItem`);
          deleteItem.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.addEventListener(`click`, function (e) {
              const mainEl = e.target.closest(`.single-item`);
              mainEl.parentNode.removeChild(mainEl);
              button.disabled = false;
            });
          });

          //add more movies btn
          const plusBtn = document.querySelectorAll(`.plus`);
          const minusBtn = document.querySelectorAll(`.minus`);

          plusBtn.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.addEventListener(`click`, function (e) {
              let plus = e.target;
              let parent = plus.closest(`.kolicina`);
              let input = parent.querySelector(`.input`);
              let singleEl = parent.closest(`.single-item`);
              let singleTotal = singleEl.querySelector(`.single-total`);

              input.value++;
              if (input.value > 3) input.value = 3;
              singleTotal.innerText = `${
                singleTotal.dataset.value * input.value
              } KN`;
            });
          });

          minusBtn.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.addEventListener(`click`, function (e) {
              let plus = e.target;
              let parent = plus.closest(`.kolicina`);
              let input = parent.querySelector(`.input`);
              let singleEl = parent.closest(`.single-item`);
              let singleTotal = singleEl.querySelector(`.single-total`);

              input.value--;
              console.log(input.innerText);
              if (input.value < 1) input.value = 1;
              singleTotal.innerText = `${
                singleTotal.dataset.value * input.value
              } KN`;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(
```

(err) => console.error(err));

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand clearly what you are trying to say. But as far as considered to append a  child  to parent div you can use

```
parentDiv.appendChild(childElement);
```

Appreciate it if you can make the question more understable.

Comment: Look on the new link I will provide it here. In the picture, I have marked with red color would I dont need here. I want to keep everything else. I hope so now you understand. This element in red square is html element called ''basketTotal'' as I mentioned in previous post. https://imgur.com/a/fy9RLI7